# scroll in FrameLayout Not working

Tags: android, xml, scroll

When I run the program works just scroll (4), while others do not work at all of them have shared a long text!!!
If you see all the text of a common format but with different Id.
Please note that all text is a long text that is fed from Java code.
here is my current layout..

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/tabbackground" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/page1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:text="Dummy Text"
                android:textSize="18sp" >
            </TextView>
        </ScrollView>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/page2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:text="Dummy Text"
                android:textSize="18sp" >
            </TextView>
        </ScrollView>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView03"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/page3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:text="Dummy Text"
                android:textSize="18sp" >
            </TextView>
        </ScrollView>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView04"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/page4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:text="Dummy Text"
                android:textSize="18sp" >
            </TextView>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fri"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



            <TextView

                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:fadeScrollbars="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:text="@string/mon">

            </TextView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: A bit of detail about what you've changed would improve this answer

Comment: just add this ,android:fadeScrollbars="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"